# solving the inequality

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I'm looking for hints on how to efficiently solve this inequality:  $$\left( \frac {|x|-|1-x|}{|x|}  \right)^{2x-1}   \gt   \left(\frac {|x|-|1-x|}{|x|} \right)^{8-x} $$

Comment: I think you may want to separate for two cases: $x>0$ and $x<0$

Comment: @elimination Actually probably also in $1-x>0$ and $1-x<0$

Comment: Right, thank you @dreamer

Answer (score 3):

Set $y = \dfrac{|x|-|1-x|}{|x|}= 1 - \lvert \frac1x-1 \rvert$.

Note $y > 1 $ is not possible, and $y \in [0, 1]$ when $x \ge \frac12$.  Otherwise $y$ is negative, (so what?).

So the only case to consider is $y \in [0, 1]$, which means $2x-1< 8-x \implies ...$

Comment: Hahah, *cough* don't look at the edit history *cough* ;)

Comment: @dreamer started writing a hint and ended up with short answer, so had to edit :(

Comment: Haha, I know, I was just kidding :)

Comment: exponential function wlays has a base whihc is greater then zero and not equal to one, and hence your said first lmitation (right?)

Comment: @Bak1139 In $b^a$, if $b < 0$, we run into trouble in defining it as a function in real numbers (unless $a$ is restricted to integers). $b=1$ is perfectly fine though.

Comment: usually 1 in the base is also thrown away since the function isn't really meaningfull. at least so we were told

Comment: @Bak1139 $f(x)=1^x = 1$ is trivially a constant, though technically a valid function. In the above problem $y=1$ is not a solution purely because the inequality is strict.

Comment: that's a good point..

Comment: Say I noticed that $ 1 - \lvert \frac1x-1 \rvert$ gains positive fractions values for $x>0.5$ and negative integer values fo $x<0.5$, do I need to prove or show it somehow, or can I use it as soon as I see it?

Comment: @Bak1139 it is easy to show, and if you are in doubt, perhaps better to do so for rigour.

Comment: not in doubt, but it's definetly not something which can be observed at first approach

Answer (score 1):

One can distinguish multiple cases

- $x>0, \ 1-x>0$
- $x>0, \ 1-x<0$
- $x<0, \ 1-x>0$
- $x<0, \ 1-x<0$

As an example,when $x<0$ and $1-x<0$ we have that the inequality reads $\left(\frac{1-x-x}{-x}\right)^{2x-1}>\left(\frac{1-x-x}{-x}\right)^{8-x}$ or equivalently $\left(\frac{2x-1}{x}\right)^{2x-1}>\left(\frac{2x-1}{x}\right)^{8-x}$

It then follows that this is true for $2x-1>8-x$ or equivalently $3x>9 \rightarrow x>3$, but this is not possible since we found this solution under the assumption that $x<0$.

You could do the same for each case. This is the most intuitive solution, but Macavity's way is nicer.